# I have a HP Desk Jet 3630. I can not always print from my computer HP Pavillion. How do I start printer?

Tags: printing

I have a HP Desk Jet 3630. I can not always print from my computer HP Pavillion. How do I start printer.

Comment: How did you add this printer to your system? CUPS, I hope. Point your browser to `http://localhost:631`